# File input not working on mobile devices (iOS/Android), but works on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form with a file input element that works as expected on desktop browsers, but it doesn't work properly on mobile devices (both iOS and Android). When I select a file on mobile, it does not get added to the file input, and consequently, the file doesn't get sent when submitting the form.

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form class="d-flex" id="messageForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="messageInput" placeholder="Type your message...">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" class="form-control-file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-2">Send</button>
</form>
```

And my JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
$('#messageForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var messageContent = $('#messageInput').val();
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

    // Create a FormData object to handle the file upload
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('sender_id', sender_id);
    formData.append('referral_id', referral_id);
    formData.append('content', messageContent);
    if (fileInput.files[0]) {
        formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
    }

    if (messageContent || fileInput.files[0]) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/messages/send_message",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === 'success') {
                    $('#messageInput').val('');
                    $('#fileInput').val('');
                    fetchMessages();
                } else {
                    alert('Error sending message');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've already tried removing the capture and accept attributes from the file input, but the issue persists. The problem only occurs on mobile devices. On desktop browsers, the file input works correctly, and the selected file is added and sent when submitting the form.

Any ideas on why the file input is not working on mobile devices and how to fix it?